# Shopping cart coupon/discount code process

Tags: asp.net, shopping-cart

I want to add coupon/discount code to custom asp.net site that already has a shopping cart. I'm looking to see if there are any resource on best practice to implement this feature in asp.net. There might also be a third-party product that is out there. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Jamal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coupon/Discount codes are both easy and tricky based on how it is implemented. 
Few questions which may help you are as follows:

- Is the coupon code item or group / item type specific ?
- Is the coupon going to be user specific if not then is there an expire date set ?
- If your shopping cart already has bundles with discounted item then is the coupon code still going to work ?
- If VAT and TAX are calculated seperatly in the shopping cart then does the discount applies before the VAT and   TAX are calculated or before?
- Are  users aloowed to use the same coupon more than once ?

Other considerations to keep in mind:

- In bundle, the user should not be able to apply the coupon code and remove an item.
- The user may frequently use the back button in the browser and so the coupon code must be 
  valdated and stored in the database only when payment is complete successfully.

Hope the above helps.

Comment: These are excellent questions. I'm trying to avoid building something from scratch since I'm new to .net and with limited resource. Would you or anyone out there know of anything out there such as third part or sample source code.

Comment: well there are many 3rd party shopping cards available built-in to CMS like Umbraco , Sitecore etc. Having said that, it will still involve effort in learning the existing framework(like Umbraco's Shopping cart framework) which is time consuming. I would suggest you to create one yourself because you are very likely to customise the shopping carts to your needs where as a generic one is not that easy to customise unless you know its framework already!! so it would be better if you just built your own BAL for shopping cart.

Comment: We already have the shopping cart. I'll take your suggestions and go from there. I'm thinking it will be just a matter off adding a text box for the coupon/prom code which will reference a database during checkout and does validation based on the prom code. I hope that I'm not making it to simple.

Comment: All the best mate! sorry i am not sure of really simple cart as you mentioned .

Comment: Thanks RaM. I appreciate your responses.